# How do you remove accents from a string in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I would like a function to remove accents from a string. Example input/output:

```
regardé -> regarde
fête    -> fete
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [`text-icu`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-icu-0.7.0.1/docs/Data-Text-ICU.html) library contains a variety of Unicode utilities. We will also need the [`text`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-1.2.2.2/docs/Data-Text.html) library in order to convert our `String`s to `Text`. I installed them by adding the following two lines to `build-depends` in my cabal file:

```
build-depends:     --- other packages...
                   , text-icu >= 0.7.0.1 && < 1
                   , text
```

With those dependencies installed, we can remove accents with the following process:

1. Convert the input `String` to `Text`
2. Normalize the input (see the [documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-icu-0.7.0.1/docs/Data-Text-ICU-Normalize.html) for why this is necessary)
3. Filter out the accents
4. Convert back to `String`.

Keeping all that in mind, we come up with the following function:

```
import Data.List
import qualified Data.Text as T
import Data.Text.ICU.Char
import Data.Text.ICU.Normalize

canonicalForm :: String -> String
canonicalForm s = T.unpack noAccents
  where
    noAccents = T.filter (not . property Diacritic) normalizedText
    normalizedText = normalize NFD (T.pack s)
```

If you don't need to convert from a `String`, you can skip the `T.pack` and `T.unpack` calls.